# code don't show when open new project in android studio

Tags: android-studio

When I make a new project in Android Studio, I don't see any code files in the "Project" pane; instead, I see "External Libraries" and "Scratches and Consoles". Android Studio used to show code. I've tried following steps in tutorials, but they all seem to automatically see the code, and don't explain how to show it. Here's a screenshot of what I see:

[image: new project in Android Studio]

Comment: The question should include version information.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see the 'Project' written over there , in the right side their is a drop down. Click over there and you can see many options, but click on the last option named "Android". Their you can find that its showing 'app' and 'Gradle Scripts'. Click on the app drop down and go to java and res file

You can see your code.